# How to make a custom shape for bottom navigation bar on Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to create bottom navigation bar shape like this on Jetpack Compose?

[image: NavBar Example]

Comment: https://juliensalvi.medium.com/custom-shape-with-jetpack-compose-1cb48a991d42 custom shape with bezeir curves should help.

Comment: do you have an answer for this yet?

Comment: were you able to draw this shape?

Answer (score 4):

Apply this shape to your `BottomNavigation`

```
private const val CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 96

// the coordinates of the first curve
private val mFirstCurveStartPoint = PointF()
private val mFirstCurveControlPoint1 = PointF()
private val mFirstCurveControlPoint2 = PointF()
private val mFirstCurveEndPoint = PointF()


private val mSecondCurveControlPoint1 = PointF()
private val mSecondCurveControlPoint2 = PointF()
private var mSecondCurveStartPoint = PointF()
private var mSecondCurveEndPoint = PointF()

class BottomNavCurve : Shape {

    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {
        return Outline.Generic(path = Path().apply {
            val curveDepth = CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4F)
            // the coordinates (x,y) of the start point before curve
            mFirstCurveStartPoint.set(
                (size.width / 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3),
                curveDepth
            )

            // the coordinates (x,y) of the end point after curve
            mFirstCurveEndPoint.set(
                size.width / 2,
                0F
            )

            // same thing for the second curve
            mSecondCurveStartPoint = mFirstCurveEndPoint;
            mSecondCurveEndPoint.set(
                (size.width / 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3),
                curveDepth
            )

            // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 1st control point on a cubic curve
            mFirstCurveControlPoint1.set(
                mFirstCurveStartPoint.x + curveDepth,
                mFirstCurveStartPoint.y
            )

            // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 2nd control point on a cubic curve
            mFirstCurveControlPoint2.set(
                mFirstCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS,
                mFirstCurveEndPoint.y
            )
            mSecondCurveControlPoint1.set(
                mSecondCurveStartPoint.x + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS,
                mSecondCurveStartPoint.y
            )
            mSecondCurveControlPoint2.set(
                mSecondCurveEndPoint.x - (curveDepth),
                mSecondCurveEndPoint.y
            )

            moveTo(0f, curveDepth)
            lineTo(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x, mFirstCurveStartPoint.y)
            cubicTo(
                mFirstCurveControlPoint1.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mFirstCurveControlPoint2.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mFirstCurveEndPoint.x, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y
            )
            cubicTo(
                mSecondCurveControlPoint1.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mSecondCurveControlPoint2.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mSecondCurveEndPoint.x, mSecondCurveEndPoint.y
            )
            lineTo(size.width, curveDepth)
            lineTo(size.width, size.height)
            lineTo(0F, size.height)
        })
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how you can use it:

```
    BottomAppBar(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(1F)
            .height(118.dp),
        backgroundColor = MyTheme.colors.transparent,
        elevation = 0.dp
    ) {
        BottomNavigation(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(1F)
                .clip(BottomNavCurve())
        ) {}
    }
```